# Mount more root folders on different partition

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, mount, root

I want to mount several root folders on my 2GB SD card so that when the cord connecting my Mint hard drive falls loose, I won't have to reboot the system.

I have already mounted `/bin` on the card. I know I can't really mount `/etc` on the card because of the bootloading process, and I know that `/sys` and `/dev` are temporary/fake directories.

What more folders (other than `/home` and `/usr`) can I mount on my SD card so that I don't have to reboot if the USB port lets the hard drive cord fall out?

Comment: Maybe beside the point, but wouldn't it be far simpler/less complicated (and more stable for the os I guess) to just fix the usb port? Like for example fixing an extension cord to the loose usb port and then using that to connect to the hard drive?

Comment: @DaJF Two USB cables? That's not going to fix the port. Any cord will become disconnected for a fraction of a second if the male part changes elevation or is slightly pulled most of the time.

Comment: That's why I suggested fixing it in place (glue, a metal bracket, soldering it), to prevent it from moving, hence having a stable connection.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent Linux from failing when the root FS goes offline, you would exactly need to move your `/` directory out of troublesome device. When the drive crashes, in order to recover/remount the volume, your system will need access to its basic tools such as `mount` or `ls`, located in `/bin` and `/sbin`, and also to their associated libraries in `/lib`.
Keeping these directories in a safe drive, you should be able to leave all the other directories into your USB disk, letting it fail and recover at will.

Additionally, you don't necessarily need to use an additional physical device to store the essential directories, you could even mount `/`, `/bin`, `/sbin` and `/lib` into a ramdisk during the execution of the `/init` script contained inside your initramfs, and relocate these directories after `nuke()` is executed.